# Information not being entered into mysql database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I have a register page where a user enters their name and email and that will send them an activation email.  This was working but i was told i need to use pdo to make it more secure.  Right now when i click submit it runs through everything without errors but a user is not added to the database.  Here is my code:

```
<?
session_start();

include 'db.php';
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$database_name", $dbusername, $dbpasswd);


// Define post fields into simple variables
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


/* Let's strip some slashes in case the user entered
any escaped characters. */

$first_name = stripslashes($first_name);
$last_name = stripslashes($last_name);
$username = stripslashes($username);
$email_address = stripslashes($email_address);



if((!$username) || (!$email_address)){
    echo 'You did not submit the following required information! <br />';
    if(!$username){
        echo "Username is a required field. Please enter it below.<br />";
    }
    if(!$email_address){
        echo "Email Address is a required field. Please enter it below.<br />";
    }
    include 'register.html'; // Show the form again!
    /* End the error checking and if everything is ok, we'll move on to
     creating the user account */
    exit();  //if the error checking has failed, we'll exit the script!
}


 if ( $password <> $confirm_password ){
    echo "<br /><strong><div style=color:#FF0000;><center>Password and confirm password do not match!<BR></center></div></strong>";
    include 'register.html';
    exit(); 
}


/* Let's do some checking and ensure that the user's email address or username
 does not exist in the database */

 $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE email_address='$email_address'");
 $sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

 $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check);
 $username_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);

 if(($email_check > 0) || ($username_check > 0)){
    echo "<br /><div style=color:#FF0000;><center>Please fix the following errors: </div><br /><br />";
    if($email_check > 0){
        echo "<strong><div style=color:#FF0000;><center>Your email address has already been used by another member in our database. Please submit a different Email address!</div><br />";
        unset($email_address);
    }
    if($username_check > 0){
        echo "<strong><div style=color:#FF0000;><center>The username you have selected has already been used by another member in our database. Please choose a different Username!</div><br />";
        unset($username);
    }
    include 'register.html'; // Show the form again!
    exit();  // exit the script so that we do not create this account!
 }

/* Everything has passed both error checks that we have done.
It's time to create the account! */

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set first_name=?, last_name=?, username=?, email_address=?, password=?");
$stmt->execute([$first_name, $lastname, $username, $email_address, $hash]);

if(!$stmt){
    echo 'There has been an error creating your account. Please contact the webmaster.';
} else {
    $userid = mysql_insert_id();
    // Let's mail the user!
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?  How do you even know that you connected to your database with no problems?

Comment: Using PDO does not, of itself, make your code more secure. Using prepared statements (not supported by mysql_*()) _will_ help. In any case, what you have here is a mish-mash of `mysql_*()` and PDO calls. Probably, nothings working.

Comment: @HoboSapiens so i need to rewrite all of my mysql_queries to make this work correctly.  That is what youre saying correct?

Comment: That's what he's saying...read the documentation for `PDO` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), modify your code, then come back here if you are still stuck.

Comment: @user3205214 You got it.

Comment: wait, you have `$dbh = new PDO(...` but using `mysql_query()` -> `$sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT...`/`$sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT...`?

Comment: You should check the result of your execute() statement for succes and then you can check for errors on $dbh using errorinfo(), http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php.

Comment: @kidbrax it looks like i am going to need to check database issues connection issues :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the last inserted ID using PDO (not `mysql_insert_id()`) you'd do this:

```
$userid = $dbh->lastInsertId();
// Let's mail the user!
```

To convert the rest of your `mysql_*` queries to PDO, you'd probably want to do something like this:

```
$sql_email_check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE email_address = :email");
$sql_email_check->execute([':email' => $email_address]);
$email_check = $sql_email_check->rowCount();

$sql_username_check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$sql_username_check->execute([':username' => $username]);
$username_check = $sql_username_check->rowCount();

if (($email_check > 0) || ($username_check > 0)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: wow man, thanks!  I just got home and i am going to look over this.  I really appreciate the time you took to type all of this up

Comment: I dont doubt that this is the correct code.  However, i am still having the same issue.  Can you tell me how i can begin trouble shooting making sure i am connected to the db?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some debugging. Have you got `error_reporting()` on, and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` set? Are you getting any PHP errors at all, are you seeing a blank white screen (syntax errors)? Have you checked database errors [like this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-errors)

Comment: so i am connecting to the db find bc when i try to register with an email address that is already registered i do get the error that an account already exists with that email address . . . .

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump()` the execute statement?

Comment: object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(99) "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, email_address, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" }

Comment: @RyanVincent nice - didn't know that. I'll remove that component.

Comment: @user3205214 not sure you're debugging the right line - [the `execute()` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) says it'll either return true or false

Comment: is this wrong? `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, email_address, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute([$first_name, $lastname, $username, $email_address, $hash]);
var_dump($stmt);`

Comment: Try `$result = $stmt->execute(...); var_dump($result);`

Comment: i got bool(false) when i did this `var_dump($stmt->execute([$first_name, $lastname, $username, $email_address, $hash]));`

Comment: false when i did it the way you suggested

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "23000" [1]=> int(1048) [2]=> string(33) "Column 'last_name' cannot be null" }   -- interesting because i am filling out a last name

Comment: Now you're getting somewhere - try `$last_name` instead of `$lastname`

Comment: ya i just went up and saw that

Comment: Awesome man thanks a lot. I really appreciate you sticking around and debugging with me.  Now that i have this working ill move on to getting the activation and logging in working.  I think i can use what i learned here to figure it out on my own hopefully.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries - glad you got it sorted.